# Using lxml and python how would I loop through all the divs within a div on a website?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml

For fun I am trying to write a script in python that goes through all the posts on the front page of a given subreddit. I have the following code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

subredditURL = "https://www.reddit.com/r/" + "pics/"
subredditPage = requests.get(subredditURL)
subredditTree = html.fromstring(subredditPage.content)
subreddit_rows_xpath = subredditTree.xpath('//*[@id="siteTable"]')

for div in subreddit_rows_xpath:
    print(div)
```

Now I thought the for loop would print out as many divs as their are posts on the page I am looking at. I think for a typical reddit subreddit's front page this would be 25 posts. The reason I thought this would work is when I manually inspect the siteTable div, it seems to contain a series of 25 divs with x_paths with the following format, within the siteTable div:

```
//*[@id="thing_t3_63fuuy"]
```

where the id seems to be a random string and there is one of these divs for each post on the front page, and they contain relevant information for the post I can explore.

Instead of printing out 25 divs the code above returns:

```
<Element div at 0x110669f70>
```

Implying only one div, not the 25 I expected. How am I going about this wrong?

Here is the link for the url I am exploring if that helps: https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/

Comment: `//*[@id="thing_t3_63fuuy"]/div`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? //*[@id="thing_t3_63fuuy"] is an example of one of the 25 div ids i see within the siteTable div.

Comment: `//div[contains(@id, "thing_t3_")]`

Comment: Ok - this looks promising - i didn't realize all the divs shared "thing_t3_" as part of their div id - but how would i use this line you provided to loop through them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `subredditTree.xpath('//*[@id="siteTable"]')` returns a list with only 1 element.  So iterating over it using:

```
for div in subreddit_rows_xpath:
    print(div)
```

only outputs 1 element, because that's all that exists.  If you want to iterate over all of the `div` elements under `subreddit_rows_xpath`, you can use:

```
subreddit_table_divs = subredditTree.xpath('//*[@id="siteTable"]//div')
for div in subreddit_table_divs:
    print(div)
```

However, I am guessing you want more than just a bunch of lines that look like `<Element div at 0x99999999999>`.  You probably want the either the title or the link to the posts.

To get the titles, you need to drill down two levels to the links:

```
subreddit_titles = subredditTree.xpath(
    '//*[@id="siteTable"]//div[@class="entry unvoted"]'
    '/p/a[@data-event-action="title"]/text()'
)
```

To get the links to the images, it is the same path, just grab the `href` attribute.

```
subreddit_links = subredditTree.xpath(
    '//*[@id="siteTable"]//div[@class="entry unvoted"]'
    '/p/a[@data-event-action="title"]/@href'
)
```